# asynchronous / variable framerate in javascript game

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, frame-rate, 2d-games

This may be a stupid/previously answered question, but it is something that has been stumping me and my friends for a little while, and I have been unable to find a good answer.

Right now, i make all my JS Canvas games run in ticks.  For example:

```
function tick(){
//calculate character position
//clear canvas
//draw sprites to canvas
if(gameOn == true)
    t = setTimeout(tick(), timeout)
}
```

This works fine for CPU-cheep games on high-end systems, but when i try to draw a little more every tick, it starts to run in slow motion.  So my question is, **how can i keep the x,y position and hit-detection calculations going at full speed while allowing a variable framerate?**

Side Note: I have tried to use the requestAnimationFrame API, but to be honest it was a little confusing (not all that many good tutorials on it) and, while it might speed up your processing, it doesn't entirely fix the problem.

Thanks guys -- any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

RequestAnimationFrame makes a **big** difference. It's probably the solution to your problem. There are two more things you could do: set up a second tick system which handles the model side of it, e.g. hit detection. A good example of this is how PhysiJS does it. It goes one step further, and uses a feature of some new browsers called a web worker. It allows you to utilise a second CPU core. [John Resig has a good tutorial](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/). But be warned, it's complicated, is not very well supported (and hence buggy, it tends to crash a lot).

Really, request animation frame is very simple, it's just a couple of lines which once you've set up you can forget about it. It shouldn't change any of your existing code. It is a bit of a challenge to understand what the code does but you can pretty much cut-and-replace your setTimeout code for the examples out there. If you ask me, setTimeout is just as complicated! They do virtually the same thing, except setTimeout has a delay time, whereas requestAnimationFrame doesn't - it just calls your function when it's ready, rather than after a set period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using the ticks. What's hapenning is that you are repeatedly calling `tick()` over and over and over again. You need to remove the `()` and just leave `setTimeout(tick,timeout);` Personally I like to use `arguments.callee` to explicitly state that a function calls itself (and thereby removing the dependency of knowing the function name).

With that being said, what I like to do when implementing a variable frame rate is to simplify the underlying engine as much as possible. For instance, to make a ball bounce against a wall, I check if the line from the ball's previous position to the next one hits the wall and, if so, when.

That being said you need to be careful because some browsers halt all JavaScript execution when a contaxt menu (or any other menu) is opened, so you could end up with a gap of several seconds or even minutes between two "frames". Personally I think frame-based timing is the way to go in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Kolink mentioned. The `setTimeout` looks like a bug. Assuming it's only a typo and not actually a bug I'd say that it is unlikely that it's the animation itself (that is to say, DOM updates) that's really slowing down your code.

How much is a little more? I've animated hundreds of elements on screen at once with good results on IE7 in VMWare on a 1.2GHz Atom netbook (slowest browser I have on the slowest machine I have, the VMWare is because I use Linux).

In my experience, hit detection if not done properly causes the most slowdown when the number of elements you're animating increases. That's because a naive implementation is essentially exponential (it will try to do `n^n` compares). The way around this is to filter out the comparisons to avoid unnecessary comparisons.

One of the most common ways of doing this in game engines (regardless of language) is to segment your world map into a larger set of grids. Then you only do hit detection of items in the same grid (and adjacent grids if you want to be more accurate). This greatly reduces the number of comparisons you need to make especially if you have lots of characters.